# How to configure storage type in MongoDB 3.0?

Tags: mongodb, storage

WiredTiger supports both row-oriented storage, and column-oriented storage. How can we specify the type we want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the [WiredTiger server parameters](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#wiredtiger-parameters) and here are the [collectionlevel parameters](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/create/#specify-storage-engine-options). You could set the key_format to enable column-orientated storage, but I have no idea if it is supported. If you try it then please report back with your results.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. With the information you provided, I finally found it in WiredTiger document. Column-orientated storage can be enabled by setting 'key_format=r' in the config string when creating the table. Here is one example.`
         /* Create a table with columns: keys are record numbers, values are
         * (string, signed 32-bit integer, unsigned 16-bit integer).
         */
        ret = session->create(session, "table:mytable",
            "key_format=r,value_format=SiH,"
            "columns=(id,department,salary,year-started)");`